# Exception / Crash When Merging CoreData Managed Contexts

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, ios5

Im getting the following exception when attempting to merge a managed context (running on a background thread) with my main managed context (on mainthread). I cant seem to catch the exception in my own @try expression. Does anyone have any insight into this issue?

I'm using the default merge policy but im not sure this is correct - this issue is very intermittent - happens rarely but is causing my app to crash.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x37e3b8bf __exceptionPreprocess + 163
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x319211e5 objc_exception_throw + 33
2   CoreData                        0x344b7ea5 -[NSSQLiteStatement cachedSQLiteStatement] + 1
3   CoreData                        0x344b774f -[NSSQLiteConnection prepareSQLStatement:] + 55
4   CoreData                        0x3455b049 -[NSSQLChannel selectRowsWithCachedStatement:] +  61
5   CoreData                        0x34586d63 newFetchedRowsForFetchPlan_MT + 783
6   CoreData                        0x344bfb07 -[NSSQLCore newRowsForFetchPlan:] + 351
7   CoreData                        0x34565011 -[NSSQLCore fetchRowForObjectID:] + 1005
8   CoreData                        0x344d1a57 -[NSSQLCore newValuesForObjectWithID:withContext:error:] + 195
9   CoreData                        0x344d0f83 _PFFaultHandlerLookupRow + 423
10  CoreData                        0x3450e111 -[NSFaultHandler fulfillFault:withContext:] + 25
11  CoreData                        0x34518999 -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _newPropertiesForRetainedTypes:andCopiedTypes:preserveFaults:] + 77
12  CoreData                        0x345178ef -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _newAllPropertiesWithRelationshipFaultsIntact__] + 79
13  CoreData                        0x345284db -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _establishEventSnapshotsForObject:] + 47
14  CoreData                        0x3452694b -[NSManagedObjectContext deleteObject:] + 155
15  CoreData                        0x345238a1 -[NSManagedObjectContext _mergeChangesFromDidSaveDictionary:usingObjectIDs:] + 813
16  CoreData                        0x34522c35 -[NSManagedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:] + 189
17  myapp                       0x0008f0e9 0x8d000 + 8425
18  CoreFoundation                  0x37d9a22b -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 43
19  Foundation                      0x31d75757 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 351
20  CoreFoundation                  0x37e0fb03 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
21  CoreFoundation                  0x37e0f2cf __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 215
22  CoreFoundation                  0x37e0e075 __CFRunLoopRun + 653
23  CoreFoundation                  0x37d914dd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 301
24  CoreFoundation                  0x37d913a5 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
25  GraphicsServices                0x3790ffcd GSEventRunModal + 157
26  UIKit                           0x35221743 UIApplicationMain + 1091
```

I init the background context in start() of a nsoperation like so:

```
AppDelegate *appController = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
_managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
[appController setPersistentStore:_managedObjectContext];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receivedDeletedObjects:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:_managedObjectContext];
```

I also set up a notification event which is called when objects are deleted on the background managed context, the callback then does:

```
-(void)receivedDeletedObjects:(NSNotification *)note
{
    AppDelegate *appController = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext = [self managedObjectContext];
[mainContext performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:) withObject:note waitUntilDone:NO];

}
```

Thats pretty much the code. I have 4 different background threads each with its own managed context doing the same thing merging with the main context in this manner. Im wondering multiple threads are getting into mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification at the same time but this shouldnt be the case as it is always called on the mainthread.

Comment: Some source code would be useful, specifically where you're doing the merge and also creating the additional context.

Comment: hi twilson ive added some code above..

Comment: Out of interest, why are you calling `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` because really all of this should be happening on the main thread already?

Comment: is `_managedObjectContext` you main thread/original context?

Comment: _managedObjectContext is the background thread context. Im calling performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:because you cant mix managedobjectcontexts on different threads. So this ensures mainContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification is called on mainthread

Comment: So, are you setting up the new context on the main thread then?

Comment: The new context (_managedobjectcontext ) is setup on a background thread inside a nsoperation object.

Comment: When I set mine up, I do so on the main thread, as per Apple's code examples, and that seems to work fine for me.

Comment: What is the rationale for having several threads with managed object contexts?

Comment: According to the Apple Documentation it is recommended that you should create a managed object context per thread, and this is how Ive designed it.

Comment: Out of curiosity what is the iOS version that crashes? Failing to merge contexts on large deletes on background thread was a known bug in iOS4.

Comment: What's the exception message? Might give a hint...

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

(all in AppDelegate, call freshContextForBackgroundTask from a background Thread and use save: to trigger the merge.) Note syncObj is a plain NSObject instance needed for synchronization within the app delegate when using many background threads (or just have bad luck with scheduling)

```
-(NSManagedObjectContext*) freshContextForBackgroundTask {
    @synchronized(syncObj) {
        NSManagedObjectContext* r = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [r setPersistentStoreCoordinator:self.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(backgroundContextDidSave:)
                                                     name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                                   object:r];
        return r;
    }
}


- (void)backgroundContextDidSave:(NSNotification *)notification {
    /* Make sure we're on the main thread when updating the main context */
    //NSLog(@"merging change: %@",notification);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
        // this for loop may not be needed for your purpose.
        for(NSManagedObject *object in [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:NSUpdatedObjectsKey]) {
            [[context objectWithID:[object objectID]] willAccessValueForKey:nil];
        }
        [self.managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];

    });
}
```

Your approach seems strange. Especially when you set your app delegate's persistent store to the (nil) one of the freshly init'ed context.